# Replacing Combination of Characters With Carriage Return C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a set of strings that all contain a combination of characters, specifically `*?*!`. I  want to replace every set of those I come across with a carriage return. I've tried a few methods so far, namely;

```
foreach (ContactsModel c in listOfContacts)
{
    c.ContactNotes.Replace("*?*!", Environment.NewLine); 
}
```

and

```
foreach (ContactsModel c in listOfContacts)
{
    c.ContactNotes.Replace("*?*!", "\r\n"); 
}
```

but neither of them are replacing the combination. Am I doing something incorrectly here? There is definitely that specific combination `*?*!` of characters in `ContactNotes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable so any method you call on them doesn't change the current string but instead returns a new one. You need to assign the result of the replace call to your string:

```
foreach (ContactsModel c in listOfContacts)
{
    c.ContactNotes = c.ContactNotes.Replace("*?*!", Environment.NewLine); 
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, although it arrived earlier than yours – your answer is more descriptive :).